# Improving Performance of my SQL Database

Tags: mysql, cpanel

Using mysqltuner i'm a bit worried at the maximum of memory sql seems to want to be able take... I just want to tune SQL to run better and understand how to do it myself.

Here's my mysqltuner results;

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.32
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysqld.log(141K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 246 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 46 error(s).
[--] 16 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2021-01-14T11:30:59.930120Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2021-01-14T11:08:52.530228Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2021-01-14T11:06:44.798420Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2021-01-14T10:58:56.636812Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2021-01-14T10:58:49.998564Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2021-01-14T10:23:15.649280Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2021-01-14T09:35:59.598495Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2021-01-14T09:35:24.591837Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 2021-01-14T09:26:15.821136Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 2021-01-14T08:23:56.658016Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2021-01-14T11:27:51.895559Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2021-01-14T11:08:49.145150Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2021-01-14T11:06:24.969477Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2021-01-14T10:58:53.419431Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2021-01-14T09:35:54.472640Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2021-01-08T08:38:07.365178Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2021-01-07T20:25:04.834240Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 525.3M (Tables: 446)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 13m 25s (63K q [79.404 qps], 358 conn, TX: 381M, RX: 20M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 91% / 9%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 2.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 38.0G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 81.0M global + 257.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 2.6G (93.59% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 38.0G (1372.84% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/63K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 6% (10/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/358)
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 56K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (5 temp sorts / 7K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 11
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 57% (3K on disk / 5K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 97% (10 created / 358 connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 16% (863 open / 5K opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(1400) is upper than number of tables(725)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (11/40K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (160 immediate / 160 locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.3% (1M used / 8M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/43.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 90.7% (118 cached / 11 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 40.0M/525.3M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (240 %): 48.0M * 2/40.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.74% (7453089 hits/ 7472246 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 72.13% (18568 hits/ 25743 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 7175 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysqld.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysqld.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64
    Read this before increasing for MariaDB 
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (40000) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (2000)

Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    table_open_cache (> 2000)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 525.3M) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=5M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

My.cnf file is basic as i don't understand all the different variables;

```
performance-schema=0
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=41943040
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=40000
innodb_file_per_table=1
bind-address=127.0.0.1
skip-name-resolve=1
performance_schema=ON
```

Any ideas or advice?

Comment: Definitely consider increasing the innodb_buffer_pool and innodb_log_file_size accordingly. There are a lot of other things that can be optimized but this will give you the highest performance boost

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Bah3j2pV

As requested, this is a web server, using 4 vcpu's and a Hypbrid SAN (SSD/15K SAS)

Comment: Thanks for data posted about 6 hours ago.   We still need for analysis, please post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Are you aware 5.7.33 is the bleeding edge version of MySQL? You may want to reconsider and use 5.7.32 that went General Availabiity on 10/19/2020 to avoid duties of finding and reporting bugs and the associated WAIT time for the open source devolopers to attempt to fix your discoveries on the next version.  We may be able to provide suggestions to allow you to keep using 5.7.33.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having performance problems, the likely solution involves indexing and/or reformulating queries.  Suggest you find the slowest query and let us advise.

Meanwhile, two settings to adjust in your 'small' 2.8GB of RAM:

- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 500M.
- `max_allowed_packet = 30M`

Answer (score 0):

Why you have such a high possible maximum memory usage?

Here we will look at the details:

Your MySQL is using the default number of `max_connections`, 150 (which really allows that number plus one for a database admin user to connect; this is why the number shown is 151).

```
[--] Total buffers: 81.0M global + 257.1M per thread (151 max threads)
```

This tells us how much buffer space that would use if all those connections were used at once. If you haven't got a calculator handy, that adds up to 38,903.1M (38.0G).

```
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 38.0G (1372.84% of installed RAM)
```

You've maxed out at 10 simultaneous connections historically, so `max_connections` can probably be significantly reduced. I'd set it to 20 as a starting point and only raise it from there if necessary.

```
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 6% (10/151)
```

More concerning, though, is how much memory was actually used.

```
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 2.6G (93.59% of installed RAM)
```

Unless you have a need to move large binary blobs in and out of the database (and if you do, please reconsider your application design), then you can significantly reduce `max_allowed_packet`. This defaults to 64M and you could set it there to cut nearly 3/4 of the memory usage (both actual and potential). If you get "packet too large" errors then you can raise it, but that needs RAM for each open connection.